# Canadian travelling with Americans to Israel

Tags: international-travel, canadian-citizens, israel

I'm a Canadian citizen travelling with an American group (only Canadian in group) to Israel. As I recall, there can be a significant difference in some European countries (Holland, etc) in how visitors from Canada are treated as compared to visitors from the US. Although this is predominantly a holdover from liberation in WWII, I was curious if a similar vein of thought may also apply to Israel for any reason.

Is there a difference in how Israelis view Canadians vs Americans?

Will it have any effect on how a traveller would be interacted with (ie. whether they have a Canadian pin while shopping, etc)?

Comment: Thanks, I left initially without verifying that answer had posted as expected due to work constraints :(.

Comment: @Kendall Even after your edit I'm unsure what exactly you're asking?  Are you expecting you might get better treatment as a non-American?  Or that you'll be treated poorly because you're not American?

Comment: I disagree on the better welcome for Canadians in the Netherlands. The group remembering WWII is getting very small. Tourists are acted to as they act. Be a loud North American, be treated as one, which ever side of the border.

Comment: Very interesting @Willeke, although I'm fairly unassuming anyway (despise the typical loud NA stereotype :) ).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I hold dual Israeli and American citizenship and lived in Israel for two years. To be honest, I don't think anybody would care. In my experience, Israelis, for the most part, love Americans. I don't think, however, you would be treated any differently because you're Canadian.

Ultimately, it's just a matter of being a good guest while you're there. If you do that, I'm sure you won't have any problems.

Enjoy the falafel and schwarma!